# How do i restrict the user input in ComboBox to only model data in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, combobox, sapui5

I have a scenario where i want to restrict user to only input text that is only loaded to the combobox as seen in this MultiComboBox example. [Take note that this is not my jsbin. please post your answer in this thread]

http://jsbin.com/sicixisozi/edit?html,js,output

in the above example, user is only allowed to enter characters that are present in the combobox, for example entering a 's' will prompt invalid entry and prevent user from typing. however, i'm not using the MultiComboBox but will be using the ComboBox instead and this function is not found in default SAPUI5 **ComboBox**

http://jsbin.com/xenidoh/embed?html,output

```
var mcb = new sap.m.ComboBox({
```

as seen in above example, user are not restricted and are able to input anything to the combobox. any suggestion how i could implement the same feature in MultiComboBox to the ComboBox?

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you want to disable typing altogether you can attach an onAfterRendering event delegate function to the ComboBox. In that function, you can disable the inputbox altogether. This means users cannot type anything into the field. You can also utilize the same function to check what the user has typed in, match it to the list displayed in the combobox and then allow or disallow typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

on the change event of the combo box check that the oComboBox.getSelectedkey() is not null or empty. If it is empty, it means that the user hasn't selected a correct value and so return an error.

```
oComboBox.attachChange(function(oEvent){
          var newval = oEvent.getParameter("newValue");
          var key = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem();


          if (newval !== "" && key === null){
            oEvent.getSource().setValue("");
            oEvent.getSource().setValueState("Error");
          }else{
            oEvent.getSource().setValueState("None");
          }

      });
```

or if you are using XML views - add the function to the `change=""`
where oComboBox is your combobox.

http://jsbin.com/vupehukena/1/edit?html,output

Comment: i'm talking about how to implement the same feature that is found in MultiComboBox to ComboBox

Comment: @user1166085 please see my updated answer - I quickly mocked something together

Comment: that's a very elegant way to implement the feature! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, u dont have to take away user's right to type. If what (s)he types does not match any key in your list, U can just slap em with an error state:

```
onLiveValidate:function(oEvent){
        var oInput= oEvent.getSource();
        var bValid= !oInput.getSelectedKey();
        oInput.setValueState(bValid ? "Error":"None");
```